# Why slow the first entrance azure cloud app?

Tags: azure

I published a cloud service on the Azure cloud.Cloud servis and server is located in the West Europe and also I am connecting in Turkey where is the east of Europe but It seems it is a little slow.

Why is the first enterance slowly ? How can I improve this site fastly ? 
I don't know very well but Do I need to always request this site ?

Can you give me any suggestions for to be fast azure cloud service ?

Comment: Yes of course , I want to learn how can create the fastest cloud app on azure ?

Comment: I mean If someone deployed his cloud app in first time , What will he do for the performance without decition localization etc.

Comment: Well, can you verify where the problem is? Is it the connection, is it the service itself, have you profiled your service in any way?! Can you verify that this is an issue of Azure, not of your implementation? Is it *really* Azure related, or your implementation which, not depending *how* it is hosted, causes the delay on the first-call (eg polling and processing large amount of db)?

Comment: No I am not profiled , I only want to learn Is it the basic situation for the azure cloud and also Is it easy to be fast performance a little changing such as permanently request

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26159/discussion-between-serkan-yilmaz-and-andreas-niedermair)

Comment: Is that an ASP.NET application? If so it needs to start IIS and precompile the pages on first request and that can take quite a long. The workaround is to do all that inside `OnStart()` so that everything has been warmed up when the first request arrives.

Comment: @sharptooth are you talking about global.asax-`OnStart()`? (you should be more clear on that!) Well, it depends on the settings of the appPool if the pool is started automatically, and therefore `OnStart()` getting triggered or not - be aware of that! Also: read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Nope, I meant role entry point `OnStart()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serkan, you would need to first make sure in your post, weather you have published a Cloud Service or a Website to Windows Azure. Based on Cloud Service (A Web Role) or a WebSite the answer to your question will be different. As you want to learn more I would explain what goes on behind.

As you suggested that your first connection is slow, I can see that happen with Windows Azure Websites. Windows Azure Websites are running in shared pool of resources and uses the concept of hot (active) and cold (inactive) sites in which if a websites has no active connection for x amount of time, the site goes into cold state means the host IIS process exits. When a new connection is made to that websites it takes a few seconds to get the site ready and working. Depend on how your first page code is, the time to load the site for the first time varies. Similar discussion is logged:
[Very slow opening MySQL connection using MySQL Connector for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393614/very-slow-opening-mysql-connection-using-mysql-connector-for-net/12394795#12394795)

With Windows Azure Cloud Service the overall application model is different. Your webrole has its own IIS server which is fully dedicated to your application and above Website limitation does not occur however there could be other reasons which could have slower page load. If you are using WebRole, then what you could do is run a page load profiler first and RD to your Azure Instance to collect the page load data to see what else you could do to boost the performance.