# Windows Azure Websites Latency

Tags: windows, azure, web, latency

for a client a run a website on Windows Azure (Websites). I run in reserved mode and have two medium insances. I run these PHP sites on Windows and I have a separate MySQL server (running on Windows). Memory enough, no high utilization, but once every minute or two minutes I have an explained higher latency (3 seconds, instead of 300 milliseconds).

Does one experience the same behaviour, or recognize this?

All happens within one Windows Azure datacenter.

When I loadtest it with a tool, the tool thinks my website runs in Redmond, how come?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing is an artifact of hot and cold websites. Windows Azure websites use a concept of hot websites for an active connection and after few seconds when there are no active connections to Azure websites, the websites becomes cold. And when a website is in cold mode it may take little longer to start in its first time however after subsequent connection the load time is very fast.

Similar discussion are found here:
[Very slow opening MySQL connection using MySQL Connector for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393614/very-slow-opening-mysql-connection-using-mysql-connector-for-net/12394795#12394795)