# Extremely high latency on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, latency

We currently self-host our website, but we've had a few downtime incidents outside of our control and we're looking at moving it into Azure. It's an ASP.NET website using Umbraco as the CMS.

Yesterday I signed up for an Azure trial, migrated a copy of our database onto an Azure SQL Server instance, spun up a new Web App and used Web Deploy to upload the app. This was my first experience with Azure, and I was pleasantly surprised at how easy it was. There were a few issues working out how to hook up my new app to my new database but overall it was a simple process.

But the performance is awful. The database is a Standard S2 and I initially created the web app on the Free tier. I was experiencing both poor download speed and latency. The first thing I tried was bumping up the Web App's scale, so I took it to Standard Medium. This seems to have fixed the download speed, but the latency is still impressively bad.

I'm using Google Chrome's network panel to test the speed. Here's what I get downloading an image from our server:

[image: On-prem low latency]

Obviously this is going to be fast as it's going over our local network, but this does at least show that the application is not the issue.

Here's what I get with Standard S2 hosted on Australia East:

[image: Azure high latency]

The speed once the download has started is not too bad, but having a 41.92s TTFB is insane! It's not consistent, sometimes I get as low as 8s, but that's still unacceptable.

I don't have this issue when visiting other sites, so my internet is not the issue. I've tried using Small S2 and Large S2 with no change in results.

Am I doing something wrong? I find it difficult to believe that every Azure customer experiences this level of performance.

EDIT: Here's what we've learned in the comments so far:

Setting Always On does not help.

Using the Azure CDN is just as slow.

Comment: You mentioned that the website is hosted in the Australia East region.  To confirm, the database is also in the same region?

Comment: Yes the DB is in Aus East, but good thought. The test file I'm requesting is a static file as well,  so theoretically DB shouldn't be touched at all.

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the file?

Comment: Sure: http://paazuretest.azurewebsites.net/images/home/home-sky-bg-2.png

Comment: I can at least verify the download speed - I am seeing 20 - 29 seconds to pull the image down.  Have you thought about trying with a CDN?

Comment: Is the site set to `Always On`?  Maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645050/windows-azure-websites-latency?rq=1

Comment: I think a CDN would only partially mask the issue. After all, I'd still have this latency when pulling dynamic content.

Comment: Always On was Off, turning it on has resulted in a bit of a boost but it's still very slow.

Comment: I take that back, I don't think Always On has improved the speed at all.

Comment: Yes, but it would prove (or disprove) that the website is the cause of the latency.

Comment: Okay, I've spun up a CDN instance. It'll take up to 60 minutes to become operational. I'm not really sure what it'll prove though.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Is the container public?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by container. I created the CDN using the Web App as the origin. According to [this article](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-the-windows-azure-cdn-for-your-web-application) this mirrors the web app's /cdn directory, so I made a rewrite rule and now I can hit the image here: http://paazuretest.azurewebsites.net/cdn/images/home/home-sky-bg-2.png but I can't yet hit it at the CDN: http://az792278.vo.msecnd.net/images/home/home-sky-bg-2.png

Comment: Okay it's working now, the CDN has very high latency too. 25s. Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with my own network's configuration. I'm not sure how to resolve it, but I can't reproduce this issue when using my phone's internet so it's clearly not an Azure problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had enormous performance problems within the Azure environment. The cause was the activation of Applications Insights. After I deactivated it, the response times were again in the millisecond range and no longer 2-3 seconds.